# Why required country dropdown Field not preventing checkout - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, required-field

The title might seem a simple fix but it is indicating it is a required field - yet checkout is allowed without an option being chosen and the select option just showing.

I am using [Change WooCommerce checkout country field default option displayed label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65265005/change-woocommerce-checkout-country-field-default-option-displayed-label/65266234#65266234) answer code to my previous question, this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_country', 'filter_form_field_country', 10, 4 );
function filter_form_field_country( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    // Only in checkout page for "billing" city field
    if ( is_checkout() && 'billing_country' === $key ) {
        $search  = esc_html__( 'Select a country / region&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ); // String to search
        $replace = esc_html__( 'Select option to pay correct tax', 'woocommerce' ); // Replacement string
        $field   = str_replace( $search, $replace, $field );
    }
    return $field;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_country']['label'] = __('Are you purchasing as a Company Y/N or from the UK?', 'woocommerce');
    $fields['billing']['billing_country']['required'] = true;

    return $fields;
}
```

Does anybody see any conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WooCommerce the country dropdown field default option has not an empty value, but "default" as value as you can see [in this source code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.8.0/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L2751)… So you need to add the following, when the selected value is "default", to avoid checkout displaying an error notice:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'checkout_validation_billing_country', 9999, 2 );
function checkout_validation_billing_country( $data, $errors ){
    // Check for any validation errors
    if ( isset($_POST['billing_country']) && $_POST['billing_country'] === 'default' ){
        $errors->add( 'validation', __('<strong>Billing Country</strong> is a required field. Please select your country.', 'woocommerce') );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Again LoicTheAztec your a star - worked a treat - sorry for delay in responding but have been out and away from the studio. Think I have upvoted and accepted the answer.